# odd behavior in separation of badges between math and math meta

Tags: bug, badges

Today I received the Yearling badge on Math SE (hooray!). I have always thought it was interesting (not bad, just interesting) that badges (but not rep) are distinct between regular Math SE and meta Math SE. Just as it is on other SE sites.

However I noticed one odd result of that. On both Math SE and meta Math SE, I have the yearling badge twice! i.e. it says x2 next to it, in my profile on either site.

Is this a bug? If badges are separate across the two areas, which I believe to be the case since no other badges are shared, that would mean I actually have FOUR Yearling badges.

At most I should have just 1x on both sites, giving me two Yearling badges. This seems justified since while I have not been active on meta, it would be awkward not to award it here since rep is shared.

Comment: Related: [Yearling Badge on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/yearling-badge-on-meta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the limiting factor is actually the amount of reputation, which as you note, is shared across both sites.

You became a member of both the Main and Meta sites some three year and 11 months ago, and it is [irrelevant for these badges](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) how active you have been (in terms of the number of days the sites were visited).  Instead:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

So for each multiple of $200$ reputation, up to the number of full years of membership, you will earn a Yearling badge.  In your case that amounts to two badges for both sites.

Comment: Oooooh I get it now. For some reason I thought it was only for the first year. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: While I'm at it: This is my first post on meta, and it got upvoted once. However I did not get a rep increase notification. Does rep on meta not count?

Comment: Oh sorry, from your link in your first comment I can see that that is the case.

Comment: BTW I was wondering how I had overlooked the description, but actually the description doesn't show "This badge can be awarded multiple times." Where did you get that quote from?

Comment: The link is given above the quote.  You can reach that page by clicking on Yearling in the Badges page.